# Wreck: Getting "Error: Invalid request payload JSON format" when posting a mp4

Tags: hapi.js, node-streams

I am trying to post a mp4 using Wreck to an Hapi end point, but I receive `Error: Invalid request payload JSON format`. Below are the routes. I suspect that I should specify a content-type of `video/mp4` from Wreck, but the doc don't tells how to do that, event the tests. Please help me find out what is wrong there:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/upload/mov',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    const source = path.join(__dirname, '../data/mov.mp4');
    const stats = fs.statSync(source);
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(source);

    const req = Wreck.request('post', '/api/upload/mov', {
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      payload: fileStream,
      maxBytes: 7073741824 // 70mb
    });

    req.on('response', (res) => {
      // code removed to try to isolate the problem

      reply({ message: 'finished' });
    });
  }
},

{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/uplaod/mov',
  config: {
    payload: {
      maxBytes: 7073741824 // 70mb
    }
  },
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    // const stream = request.pipe(request.response);
    // code removed to try to isolate the problem

    reply({ message: 'sent' });
  }
}
```

Comment: `Content-type` is an HTTP header. Do the docs tell you how to specify headers?

Comment: It is still me, the same guy on github (-_-), still testing ... Thanks